# Spacing in multiple choice question

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, positioning

I tried to make multiple choice question using the following code...
but the choices are not uniformly distributed in a single line...

I used `\hfill` by replacing `\penalty -50\hskip 2em plus 2em\relax`... it works well when the choices occupies in single line, but when choice takes second line, the result is bad... I want to have two choices for each line when choices takes more than one lines...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcounter{choice}
%\renewcommand\thechoice{\Alph{choice}}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\alph{choice}}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice.}

\newenvironment{choices}%
{\list{\choicelabel}%
{\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
\settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%
\def\choice{%
\item} % choice
\labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth -\labelsep
\topsep=0pt
\partopsep=0pt}%
}%
{\endlist}

\newenvironment{oneparchoices}%
{%
\setcounter{choice}{0}%
\def\choice{%
\refstepcounter{choice}%
\ifnum\value{choice}>1\relax
\penalty -50\hskip 2em plus 2em\relax
\fi
\choicelabel
\nobreak\enskip
}% choice
% If we're continuing the paragraph containing the question,
% then leave a bit of space before the first choice:
\ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
\ignorespaces
}%
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice George
\choice Paul
\choice John
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{oneparchoices}


\item Which one doesn't belong?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice George
\choice Paul
\choice John
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{oneparchoices}


\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}

\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}

\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}

\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{oneparchoices}


\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?

  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve you problem. The biggest one is to decide whether the contents is more the two lines. I think a `trivlist` isn't able for such a think. So I decided to use a combination of a `hbox` and `vbox`. First I save the contents of `oneparchoices` inside a `\hbox` and test the width. If the width is greater than the current `linewidth` the box will be switched to a `vbox`. The definition of `choise` allows the needed line breaks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[choices]{label=\alph*}
\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\alph{choice}}
\setcounter{choice}{0}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{oneparchoices}%
{\ifvmode\leavevmode\else\par\unskip\fi%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{choice}{0}%
  \def\choice{%
    \stepcounter{choice}%
    \ifnumodd{\value{choice}}{\newline}{\hspace*{2.5em}}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{choice}}{1}%
        {\hspace{3em}}{}%
   \thechoice.\hspace*{.5em}\null
    }
  \setbox\z@\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces%
  }{%
  \egroup%
  \ifdimgreater{\wd\z@}{\linewidth}{%
    \setbox\z@\vbox{\hsize=\linewidth\unhbox\z@}%
    \makebox[\linewidth][l]{\box\z@}%
    }%
    {%
     \makebox[\linewidth][l]{\box\z@}%
    }%
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\LetLtxMacro{\choice}{\item}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\choice One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?%
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice George
\choice Paul 
\choice John
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{oneparchoices}

\choice Which one doesn't belong?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice George
\choice Paul
\choice John
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{oneparchoices}


\choice One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}

\choice What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}

\choice One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}

\choice What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{oneparchoices}


\choice What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?

  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Some feedback would be kind.